# Ruby: Strings do not match

Tags: ruby

I am testing two strings to see if they are equal.
One string is just a simple string: `"\17"`
The other is parsed to: `"\17"`

```
num = 7
num2 = "\17"

parsed_num = "\1#{num}"

puts parsed_num.class
puts num2.class

if parsed_num == num2
  puts 'Equal'
else
  puts 'Not equal'
end
```

It returns:

```
String

String

Not equal
```

My goal is to have `parsed_num` exactly the same as the literal `num2`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am going to take the opposite answer and assume that "\17" is *correct*, then consider [this code](http://codepad.org/Unz8xgwf):

```
num = 7
num2 = "\17"
puts "ni  #{num2.inspect}"

# extra \ to fix error, for demo
parsed_num = "\\1#{num}"
puts "pi  #{parsed_num.inspect}"

# for note, but ICK!!!
p2 = eval('"' + parsed_num + '"')
puts "p2i #{p2.inspect}"
puts "p2= #{p2 == num2}"

dec = (10 + num).to_s.oct
p3 = dec.chr
puts "p3i #{p3.inspect}"
puts "p3= #{p3 == num2}"
```

Result:

```
ni  "\017"
pi  "\\17"
p2i "\017"
p2= true
p3i "\017"
p3= true
```

The reason why `"\1#{num}"` didn't work is that string literals -- and the embedded escape sequences -- are handled during *parsing* while the string interpolation itself (`#{}`) happens later, at run-time. (This is required, because who knows what may happen to be in `num`?)

In the case of `p2` I used `eval`, which parses and then executes the supplied code. The code there is equivalent to `eval('"\17"')`, because `parsed_num` contained the 3-letter string: `\17`. (Please note, this approach is *generally considered bad*!)

In the case of `p3` I manually did what the parser does for string interpolation of `\octal`: took the value of `octal`, in, well, octal, and then converted it into the "character" with the corresponding value.

Happy coding.

Comment: `p3.encoding` is 'US-ASCII', `num2.encoding` is 'UTF-8' so they are not "exactly the same" in a sense.

Comment: @undur_gongor Thanks for pointing that out, I am internalization-inept :(

Answer (score 3):

If you're using "\17" backslash escape, it will be interpreted as as "\0017", where 17 would be an octal digit equals to 'F' hex:

```
"\17"  # => "\u000F"
```

because your string uses double quotes.

You can achieve what you want with help of this snippet, for example:

```
num = 7
num2 = "\\17"
parsed_num = "\\1#{num}"
if parsed_num == num2
  puts 'Equal'
else
  puts 'Not equal'
end
# => Equal
```

As you can see you get this result with help of the backslash to escape another backslash :)

Comment: Is it possible to get them both equal without changing num2

Comment: If you change `parsed_num` from `"\1#{num}"` to `"\xF"` for example

Answer (score 1):

Use single quotes so that the strings involved are the literal things you are setting:

```
num = 7
num2 = '\17'

parsed_num = '\1' + String(num)
if parsed_num == num2
  puts 'Equal'
else
  puts 'Not equal'
end
```

This produces 'Equal' - the desired result. [Here's a link](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Strings) with more info on the differences between single quoted strings and double quoted strings if desired.

Comment: Is it possible to get them both equal without changing num2